# Eclipse not using the specified JDK

Tags: java, eclipse, java-8

Eclipse was so far using the installed jre "jre1.8.0_261". I want eclipse to use jdk. I have changed the eclipse.ini and have added the following :-
-vm
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_191\bin\javaw.exe

Moreover, I have changed the windows preferences with Installed JREs as the one offered by the jdk "jdk1.8.0_191". The java build path has been also aligned to use "jdk1.8.0_191" .

However under the configuration of Eclipse IDE Installation, I could still see that Eclipse is using the previously used jre version as vm.
-vm
C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_261\bin\server\jvm.dll

However, I want Eclipse only to use the mentioned JDK. Is there any solution to this?

Comment: Do you just want to set `JAVA_HOME` and call it a day?

Comment: Do you want to use the JDK for YOUR project or do you need eclipse to run with a specific JDK? (And mind telling me why you need eclipse to run with a specific JDK, out of curiosity.)

Comment: `-vm` is to specify the Java to run Eclipse with and can be different from the JDKs/JREs you use for your applications. For the last, configure the JDKs/JREs in the preferences in _Java > Installed JREs_.

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl:- JAVA_HOME has been changed to the mentioned path of jdk and then restarted. No luck1

Comment: @JohannesKuhn : JRE alone is not enough to compile the Java program. It is the requirement of the project to use jdk1.8.0_261. I am using "jdk1.8.0_191" to satisfy the requirement

Comment: @howlger - I want Eclipse to consider that particular jdk for all the projects in general going forward.

Comment: Then go to the preferences (Window -> Preferences ->Java -> Installed JREs)  and select the JDK as default.

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse can use one Java distribution to run Eclipse, and any Java distribution to compile code with.  It can certainly use a different distro to run than it uses to compile code.  You can even have different projects using different distros.

It's probably best to have a single "-vm" option in the "eclipse.ini" file, which specifies the latest version of Java (I suppose it's possible it could just be a JRE, but I haven't tried that).  Then, install the JDK of whatever version you need, and specify that in the "Installed JREs" list.  Make sure that the page underneath that, "Execution Environments" maps the "JavaSE-1.8" to your installed JDK.